# std::enable_if, template specialization and inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, multiple-inheritance, template-specialization, enable-if

I would like to ask you about some advices about this code. It works, but I think it can be written in a more elegant way. It's a C++11 piece of code, so keep it in mind when you compile it ;) !

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

class A {};
class B: public A {};

class C {};
class D: public C {};

class E: public A, public C {};

template<class T, typename = void>
class Example;

template<class T>
class Example<T, typename enable_if<is_base_of<A, T>::value and not is_base_of<C, T>::value>::type>
{
  public:
    string a() const
    {
      return string(typeid(T).name()) + " have A as base class";
    }
};

template<class T>
class Example<T, typename enable_if<not is_base_of<A, T>::value and is_base_of<C, T>::value>::type>
{
  public:
    string b() const
    {
      return string(typeid(T).name()) + " have C as base class";
    }
};

template<class T>
class Example<T, typename enable_if<is_base_of<A, T>::value and is_base_of<C, T>::value>::type> :
    public Example<A>,
    public Example<C>
{
};

int
main()
{
  Example<B> example1;
  Example<D> example2;
  Example<E> example3;

  cout << example1.a() << endl;
  //cout << example1.b() << endl;   It must raise a compile error
  //cout << example2.a() << endl;   It must raise a compile error
  cout << example2.b() << endl;
  cout << example3.a() << endl;
  cout << example3.b() << endl;
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to write a class template that can handle classes derived from *A* and *C*. The problem is when *A* and *C* are either inherited as for class *E*. In fact we could also have something like this...

```
template<class T>
class Example<T, typename enable_if<is_base_of<A, T>::value> { /* ... */ };

template<class T>
class Example<T, typename enable_if<is_base_of<C, T>::value> { /* ... */ };
```

...but it will fail when a class (like *E*) inherits either *A* and *C*.

Any ideas for a better code?
Thanks

Comment: It's not clear enough what you want to do with this. Obviously you can't call `b()` for `Example<B>` because it only implements `a()`, and vice versa for `Example<D>`. You simply need to fill in the missing methods. Can those methods exist? Can't tell from the given information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simpler way is to use a `static_assert`.

```
template <typename T>
class Example
{
public:
    std::string a() const
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, "T must derive from A to use a()");
        return std::string(typeid(T).name()) + " have A as base class";
    }

    std::string b() const
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<C, T>::value, "T must derive from C to use b()");
        return std::string(typeid(T).name()) + " have C as base class";
    }
};
```

Comment: Ok, simpler that I could imagine... I thought Example<A>::b would be compiled also when not used, generating a compile-time error... You opened my mind! Thanks!!